# How to convert a .htaccess to web.config?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-config

I have to convert a htaccess to a web.config.

The main redirects are removing the old .aspx extension. Then a few single redirects for re-named files.

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # redirect aspx to extensionless
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.aspx$ $1 [NC,L,R=301]

 # old page redirects
 Redirect 301 /folder/old-file http://www.website.com/new-file
 Redirect 301 /folder/old-file-2 http://www.website.com/new-file-2

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS this rule will be:

```
<rule name="redirect aspx to extensionless" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.+)\.aspx$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>            
<rule name="old 1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folder/old-file$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.website.com/new-file" />
</rule>         
<rule name="old 2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^folder/old-file-2$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.website.com/new-file-2" />
</rule>
```